# Count the number of columns in an array with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$array = Get-Process
```

Now, I want to count the number of columns. I have tried:

```
$array.Columns.Count
$array.Columns
```

And all without luck.

What should I do to get the correct number of columns? That should be 8.

<<Added on January, 27th, 2021: >>

I have modified the code to:

```
$Processes = @(Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, Description, ProductVersion, @{Name="Application";Expression={$_.Description + " " + $_.ProductVersion}},@{Name="Executable";Expression={(($_."Path").split("\"))[-1]}} |Where {$_.Executable})
$Array     = @()
$Record    = [ordered] @{"Name"         = "";
                         "Application"  = ""}

ForEach ($ProcesName in $Processes)
{
 $Record."Name"        = $ProcesName.Name
 $Record."Application" = $ProcesName.Application
 $objRecord            = New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
 $Array               += $objRecord
}
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Number of columns: $($Array.Column.Count)"
Write-Host "Number rows:       $($Array.Count)"
```

The result is the same: both the column and row are the same. And that is not correct. I want to use the technique in a new script with much more columns.

<<End part that has been added on January, 27th, 2021 >>

Feedback is appreciated.

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Comment: What you see in the display is a default view for that particular object type. The actual number of properties is much greater. I don't know the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` is an array of objects of type `System.Diagnostics.Process`.  There aren't columns as such.  The objects have properties which you may choose to display in columns using `$array | ft` or as a list `$array | fl *`. You can count the properties like this:

```
$array | Get-Member -MemberType Property | measure
```

If you'd like the answer to be 8 then you can do this:

```
$array | select Handles, NPM, PM, WS, CPU, Id, SI, Name | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | measure
```

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your feedback. I thought it was a simple question... Not. I have modified the question, see the part that has been added today.

Comment: I just had a brainwave: ($Array | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | measure).Count